# Data from API call not filling inside of method

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I decided to go with an embedded API call within a view controller, and I'm having trouble with the data reaching out before the API returns with the information.

How do I wait for the data to be returned before the view controller displays all the values as nulls?

Thanks for any help.

```
#import "BDChangeApproveController.h"
#import "BDItemChangeDetailAPI.h"

@interface BDChangeApproveController () <NSURLSessionDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSession *session;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *APIItem;

@end


@implementation BDChangeApproveController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)fetchFeedAPIChangeDetail
{

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
_session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config
                                         delegate:nil
                                    delegateQueue:nil];

NSString *requestString = @"http://URL.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
[self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                completionHandler:
 ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

     NSDictionary *jsonObject1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                 options:0
                                                                   error:nil];
     //NSLog(@"%@", jsonObject1);
     self.APIItem = jsonObject1[@"CoDetail"];
     NSLog(@"%@", self.APIItem);

 }];

[dataTask resume];

}

//API authentication

- (void)  URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler
{
NSURLCredential *cred =
[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"demouser"
                           password:@"secret"
                        persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, cred);
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
[self fetchFeedAPIChangeDetail];
self.title = @"Action";
self.coNumberLabel.text = self.itemAPI.changeOrder;
//self.recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.recipe.image];

NSLog(@"testtttt");

NSMutableString *coDetailsText = [NSMutableString string];
coDetailsText =
 [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Review Change Order details bellow\n====================\n%@ \n================== \nPlanned Start %@\n==================\nSubcategory: %@\n==================\nService: %@\n==================\nAssociated CIs: %@\n==================\nEnvironment CI: %@\n==================\nApproval Group: %@\n==================\nInitiator : %@\n==================\nCoordinator : %@\n==================\nRisk Level : %@\n==================\nPerforming Group : %@\n==================\nImplementation Plan : %@\n==================\nStatus : %@\n==================\nRecovery Plan : %@\n==================\n",

 /*
 self.item.title,
 self.item.changeOrder,
 self.item.subcategory,
 self.item.assignmentGroup,
 self.item.changeOrder,
 self.item.subcategory,
 self.item.assignmentGroup,
 self.item.approverEid,
 self.item.approverEid,
 self.item.subcategory,
 self.item.assignmentGroup,
 self.item.title,
 self.item.title,
 self.item.title
 */


 self.itemAPI.title,
 self.itemAPI.plannedStart,
 self.itemAPI.subcategory,
 self.itemAPI.service,
 self.itemAPI.associatedCi,
 self.itemAPI.environment,
 self.itemAPI.assignmentGroup,
 self.itemAPI.initiator,
 self.itemAPI.coordinator,
 self.itemAPI.riskLevel,
 self.itemAPI.performingGroup,
 self.itemAPI.implementationPlan,
 self.itemAPI.status,
 self.itemAPI.recoveryScope


// self.item.valueInDollars,
// self.item.dateCreated,
// self.item.subcategory,
// self.item.service,
// self.item.associatedCIs,
// self.item.environment,
// self.item.approvalGroup,
// self.item.initiator,
// self.item.coordinator,
// self.item.riskLevel,
// self.item.performingGroup,
// self.item.implementationPlan,
// self.item.validationPlan,
 //self.item.recoveryScope

 ];


self.coDetailsTextView.text = coDetailsText;
NSLog(@"overrrr");

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

// Adding File

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BDItemChangeDetailAPI.h"

@interface BDChangeApproveController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *coNumberLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *coDetailsTextView;


@property (nonatomic, strong) BDItemChangeDetailAPI *itemAPI;


@end
```

Comment: try calling fetchFeedApiChangeDetail in -viewWillLoad method instead of viewDidLoad and if you want to make it wait don't display values unless information is returned from the api and then afterwards refresh the view. btw what are using to display the result tableview,collection view ?

Comment: I have it linked to a text cell on the story board.  That part is working ok, it's just listing all Null values.  How do I refresh the view once the API call is finished?  Do I put it inside the API call?

Comment: set the textCell value again to the result after the Api call is completed and then call setNeedsDisplay method on the textcell to let it refresh itself and display the new value. btw what do you mean by a text cell ? text cell in a table view ar just a plain label please name the control u are using

Comment: Sorry Meant text box.  I'm new to IOS so I'm still learning.

Comment: There is no control named TextBox in iOS. Are you talking about UITextView or a UILabel ? btw check if you are initializing your NSArray. and then try to log your api result that whether it is returning any values.

Comment: UITextView.  That's it.  Looks like a text box.

Comment: On a side-note, you have self.itemAPI and self.APIItem.. I assume one is a typo?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're doing something asynchronously and expecting it to act synchronously.

Look at the below piece of code you're using in viewDidLoad:

```
[self fetchFeedAPIChangeDetail]; // this takes some time to complete
self.title = @"Action"; // this happens immediately after the above starts, not ends
self.coNumberLabel.text = self.itemAPI.changeOrder; // so does this, so at this point itemAPI is probably nil
```

fetchFeedAPICheckDetail is an asynchronous process, so it might take a few seconds to complete, whereas setting the title and coNumberLabel happens immediately after, so you don't yet have the itemAPI information from the URL Session. Your code doesn't wait for fetchFeedAPIChangeDetail to be done with the request before continuing onto the next line.

Comment: Yessir.  This is the exact problem.  I'm trying to find out how to get it to wait until the data is returned to move on, or to refresh the labels at the end up the data retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a function

```
-(void)refreshTextView
{
// set your text view text with the api result here 
self.coNumberLabel.text = self.itemAPI.changeOrder; 

}
```

Call this method in at the end of your request block after  `NSLog(@"%@", self.APIItem);`
Like this

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshTextView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

When you will call this method in the block it will be called and will update the textview text with the api results. The block is asynchronous and so when you update your textview later it doesn't gets updated because the block has not yet completed its function and the array is still nil but calling this method in the block would assure that the result gets assigned and updated in the textview.

`UPDATE`

and you do have a typo here

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *APIItem;
```

you are naming it with the class name thats a conflict.
Name it something else like `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *apiItem;` Actually u have a class name `APIItem` declared because of which a conflict occurs and that is the very reason it is marked blue in xcode. look all class names are marked blue in your code. Like `NSArray , NSURLSession etc –`

Comment: When you say text view and api item, do you mean the NSMutableArray I'm pushing into the UITextView, and APIItem?

Comment: by api item I mean the array which you are using to store the result of the api call and text view which you are using to display the results.

Comment: On the conflict, how would I resolve? name it elsewhere?

Comment: no name it something else like @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *apiItem; Actually u have a class name APIItem declared because of which a conflict occurs and that is the very reason it is marked blue in xcode. look all class names are marked blue in your code. Like NSArray , NSURLSession etc

Comment: If I change it at the class level it throws an error here

    self.APIItem = jsonObject1[@"CoDetail"];
         NSLog(@"%@", self.APIItem);

Comment: Please post the description of the error here !  btw if u change the name in the declaration you must use the same name everywhere else to refer it. if you declare an NSArray *apiItem you must use apiItem to refer to that NSArray.So in this case you would use self.apiItem instead of self.APIItem if you have declared it like this @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *apiItem;

Comment: I changed the name and references, and it seems to be ok now.  How should I define it in the refreshTextView?  self.APIItem2=itemAPI; doesn't work with the error "Use of undeclared Indentifer 'itemAPI'; did you mean '_itemAPI'? " I don't have _itemAPI declared anywhere specifically either though.

Comment: ok but have you declared itemApi if yes then synthesize the property `@synthesize itemApi;`after this line in your m file `@implementation BDChangeApproveController` and there is no need to assign it if you have already assigned the result in the block. Just assign the result to the textview text to display it in the textview in the refreshTextView

Comment: I added my .h file to the original post and synthesized in my .m.  It's still acting the same way though.